# Creating Unique ID with Sequential Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, uniqueidentifier

I found what I thought would help me create a unique ID for each row of data in an Excel spreadsheet.
[image: PIC of Sheet]

Ideally, I would like to automate this with maybe VBA and a button or trigger of some sort, but I could start with just a formula. I have rows of data with the first cell being the group number.  Then each row of data within each group is unique.  The problem is I need to assign a basic ID to each row starting with 1 and up to however many are in the group.  The data is dynamic and constantly changing, so each time changes are made, I need to filter out the group and manually fill down the numbers.  I found this formula (returning the number value in column D but looking for group numbers in A), but it does not work.

=IF(A2="1",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")

Is there another way? Different function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for incremental values in D within each group, paste this formula into D2 cell and drag it all the way down:

```
=IF(A1 <> A2, 1, D1 + 1)
```

Comment: If for some reason the group numbers are not together, would there be a way for it to look for all the rows of that group and keep the sequence going?

Comment: It would be more complicated than that, but workaround would be to sort all rows and then apply my answer.

Comment: That makes sense. Simple and clean that way.